# Getting webpage opened in another tab from hyperlink of current webpage in webview of javafx browser

Tags: javafx

I have developed a very simplified but fully functional JavaFX web browser for illustrating what I want to ask. Here follows the source code.

```
public class OpenInNewTab extends Application {    
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();       

    WebView webView = new WebView();

    Tab tab = new Tab("Home Tab");
    tab.setContent(webView);

    tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

    webView.getEngine().load("https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=javafx");

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setTop(tabPane);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 339);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Basic browser");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}    
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
} }
```

This browser loads a web page from this [link](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=javafx). I want that when I click on any of the search results, the clicked hyperlink should open in new tab adjacent to the existing "Home tab".

After searching on the internet extensively, I reached nowhere.

Please help me with relevant code. Thanks.

Comment: `After searching on the internet extensively, I reached nowhere` The exact same solution that you just accepted for your question was in a link that I posted yesterday in a comment to your other (very similar) question! Couldn't you have read my comment before posting a new question? [here](http://blogs.kiyut.com/tonny/2013/07/30/javafx-webview-addhyperlinklistener/)

Comment: Thanks to you, but I had already tried your link. However the answer which I accepted was directly in the form that was illustrative for me. Though I desired right click in place of left click, I had to content with what I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to find a way to handle all outgoing click events on the displayed page. I've made a helper method to achieve that. It creates an event listener for each link, clicking on which will open a new tab.

```
private void handleUrls(Document doc) {
    NodeList links = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (int i = 0; i < links.getLength(); i++) {
        EventTarget eventTarget = (EventTarget) links.item(i);
        String link = links.item(i).toString();
        eventTarget.addEventListener("click", e -> {
            WebView webView = new WebView();
            alterWebView(webView);

            Tab tab = new Tab(link);
            tab.setContent(webView);
            tab.setClosable(true);

            webView.getEngine().load(link);

            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    }
}
```

You may want to set a better name for your tab... I've used a link as a makeshift solution, but it's long and messy.

```
webView.getEngine().load(link);
```

The `alterWebView` referenced above is another helper function. It's responsible for tracking the loading progress. Once the `Worker` does nothing, it will add listeners to all urls.

```
private void alterWebView(WebView webView) {
    WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
    Worker worker = engine.getLoadWorker();

    worker.stateProperty().addListener((oldVal, newVal, o) -> {
        if (newVal.equals(State.RUNNING)) {
            handleUrls(engine.getDocument());
        }
    });
}
```

So basically, the logic behind the code above is as follows:

- We track our `WebEngine`'s `State` until the page is fully loaded and then we add event listeners to every url.
- These listeners, when invoked, will create a new `WebView`, handle it accordingly, and add it to the `TabPane` inside a new `Tab`.

And here's the complete, working example based on your code:

```
public class JavaFXTest extends Application {

    private TabPane tabPane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        tabPane = new TabPane();
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        alterWebView(webView);

        Tab tab = new Tab("Home Tab");
        tab.setContent(webView);
        tab.setClosable(true);

        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

        webView.getEngine().load("https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=javafx");

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(tabPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 339);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Basic browser");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void alterWebView(WebView webView) {
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        Worker worker = engine.getLoadWorker();

        worker.stateProperty().addListener((oldVal, newVal, o) -> {
            if (newVal.equals(State.RUNNING)) {
                handleUrls(engine.getDocument());
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleUrls(Document doc) {
        NodeList links = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (int i = 0; i < links.getLength(); i++) {
            EventTarget eventTarget = (EventTarget) links.item(i);
            String link = links.item(i).toString();
            eventTarget.addEventListener("click", e -> {
                WebView webView = new WebView();
                alterWebView(webView);

                Tab tab = new Tab(link);
                tab.setContent(webView);
                tab.setClosable(true);

                webView.getEngine().load(link);

                tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

                e.preventDefault();
            }, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks!! I compiled and ran your code. It worked excellent! Once again I thank you for your prompt and accurate response.

Comment: Good to hear that :) You can mark my answer as accepted so that other users will see that you've found a solution.

Comment: I shall be very glad to that. As I am very new user, I shall have to find out how to mark your answer as accepted, but I shall definitely do that. The way you explained the logic was also very appreciable. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Dth Would it be better to call `handleUrls` on `State.SUCCEEDED`? This would make sure that the DOM is completely loaded.